# MongoDB sort by value in nested array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, sorting, nested, min

I have a collection called datos_sensores which documents store data from 2 sensors, one for temperature and humity and other one for CO2 and consume. There are 2 location for those sensors, location_id:1 and location_id:2. The documents has the following structure, in example:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("632eccf6c4c33123d451e23f"),
    timestamp: '2020-07-02T17:45:00Z',
    sensor_id: 1,
    location_id: 2,
    medidas: [
      { tipo_medida: 'Temperatura', valor: 36.76, unidad: 'ºC' },
      { tipo_medida: 'Humedad_relativa', valor: 3.77, unidad: '%' }
    ]
  }
```

I want to get the minimum value of location_id:2 of the element "valor" inside of the array "medidas". However, if you pay attetion, there are 2 valor fields. I want to get the minimum Temperature value, and not the minimum Humity value (Humedad_relativa). I tried the following:

```
sensores_IoT> db.datos_sensores.find({"medidas.tipo_medida":"Temperatura",location_id:2}).sort({"medidas.valor":1}).limit(1)
```

And got this answer:

```
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("632ecd14c4c33123d451e67d"),
    timestamp: '2020-07-05T14:00:00Z',
    sensor_id: 1,
    location_id: 2,
    medidas: [
      { tipo_medida: 'Temperatura', valor: 39.51, unidad: 'ºC' },
      { tipo_medida: 'Humedad_relativa', valor: 0.3, unidad: '%' }
    ]
  }
]
```

As you can see, I am getting the list sorted by humity and not for temperature. How can I tell to mongo to sort by the value tipo_medida.valor of the Temperature?

After that, I need to use $mul to multiply the value by 1.2, but I think it's quite easy to do once I have the objected filtered.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Does your medidas array only contain two elements every time?

Comment: Hello Charchit.

Yes.. its measures from 2 sensores that are storing data every 15 minuts during 14 days. Here is another document soy you can have an idea:

{
    _id: ObjectId("632ecce8c4c33123d451df95"),
    timestamp: '2020-07-01T03:15:00Z',
    sensor_id: 1,
    location_id: 1,
    medidas: [
      { tipo_medida: 'Temperatura', valor: 14.59, unidad: 'ºC' },
      { tipo_medida: 'Humedad_relativa', valor: 88.76, unidad: '%' }
    ]
  },

Comment: @CharchitKapoor and every time only contains "tipo_medida", "valor" and "unidad"

Comment: How many sensors do you have? Why are you only looking at `location_id:2` in this question? How often do these sensors capture data?

Comment: Hi, @user20042973. Sensor_id 1 and sensor_id 2. I am only looking into location_id:2 because the main problem is to find the minimum temperature for that sensor, sorry for didnt specify that. The sensors capture data every 15 min during 14 days. Starting july the first.

Answer (score 1):

This should work, here we are first sorting by `medidas.tipo_medida`, and then by `medidas.valor`:

```
db.datos_sensores.find({"medidas.tipo_medida":"Temperatura",location_id:2})
                 .sort({"medidas.tipo_medida": -1,"medidas.valor":1}).limit(1)
```

Comment: That works perfectly fine! However, I would like to understand more in deep the sort({"medidas.tipo_medida": -1. 
Is it used because 'Temperatura' starts with 'T' and 'Humedad' with 'H', right?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes. First, we sort by `medidas.tipo_medida` in descending order, and for equal values of `medidas.tipo_medida` we sort by `medidas.valor` in ascending order.

Comment: Everything clear now. Thank you very much again. I can not give "this answer was useful" due to my reputation level... but, please, consider it as done :P.

Comment: No issues. But where exactly `this answer was useful` comes, usually people mark the answer as correct, and that's it. Where does this shows up?

Comment: Ah, just realized that there are 2 types of feedback:
-Tickout: Accept this answer
-Arrow up: This answer is useful.

Just marked your answer as accepted since is the only one that the pages let to me, for now

Comment: Cool cool, thanks, I guess the one you were talking of before was upvoting.